# data persistence for pubnub chat with rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I have a rails application and want to integrate 1:1 chat + group chat. I saw some tutorials with pubnub which can easily add in the real-time functionality through pub/sub.

On the data persistence level, I am wondering if I should just store the chat messages with PostgresQL in the backend..?

A bit of info, the app is currently in production and are serving 50-80K chat requests a day, and now have around 500K messages, I wonder what I should do.

Thansk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use our History API, and leave the storage to us? ;)

https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ruby/api/reference.html#history

Comment: What if I want a record of the message history and use it for analysis and record ?

Comment: You would need to subscribe to every channel that is created and store them in your database. It is possible and has been done but this is a challenge for you to scale on your server side. You'll want to discuss this with your Customer Success Rep for best practices.

Comment: You can use PubNub's [Storage and Playback](http://www.pubnub.com/products/storage-and-playback/) for fetching historical records for data mining and analytics.  Upon fetching the past messages, you can either save them to your own OLAP/MySQL or EMR/Hadoop or RedShift data mining tools.

Comment: How long of history does pubnub store?

Comment: Chris, its completely customizable.. from 24 hours, to forever. If you shoot us a line at support@pubnub.com, we'd be happy to walk you through the feature and its options in detail.  You can try it with no obligation to purchase until you are convinced it will solve your business problem.